# Need to put [Authorize] protection on ODataController metadata endpoint, but can't

Tags: security, odata

While we are using the ODataController (meant of "open" data queries), we actually want to use it ONLY for a custom application. Since we already know what the EDM is, we don't need the metadata information. For diagnostic purposes, we want it to be available only to people who are subscribed and have certain claims.

I've tried just putting the `[Authorize]` attribute on the ODataController, but that's not preventing access. I can't see anything in the ODataConventionModelBuilder that will "hide" the metadata either.

I'm assuming this is handled lower down in the pipeline, and I might have to write an HttpHandler of some kind.

Any suggestions?